# How to Store images in Django deployed on Google App engine?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have just started using GAE and can't figure out how to store images.
I created Django project and deployed on GAE using the methodology in this 
[tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) which use cloud SQL (my project uses MySQL)

Now I want to add a Django model for images. I can't figure out how to go about it. I used AWS extensively earlier and stored links in MySQL database while filing on buckets.

Do I need to use google cloud storage? What is the GAE way to do it?

Comment: You need to see cloud storage or another CDN. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/serving-static-files .

Comment: Google also has cloud storage, with buckets, similar to AWS. You'll just have to create a bucket on GCS and add a storage backend that supports GCS to your pip requirements (and configure your settings to use that storage backend). there's a couple of options out there (e.g. django-storages supports GCS). The rest should then work as you're used to with S3.

Comment: Thanks guys, ended up using cloud storage